# Where is Hector in Cythera?

Tags: cythera

According to the [Cythera Wiki](http://cythera.wikia.com/wiki/Hector), Hector (Hadrian's son) should be in Land King Hall. Where in this large area is he?

Comment: @Texenox: Thanks for the edit. I wasn't able to create new tags yet. :-)

Comment: No problem. Glad to know it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hector can be found roaming the main East-West hallway from time to time. If you can't find him, pace the entire hallway, or try again later.